# How to specify which scrollviewer should be used

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

Consider the following scenario representing a list of items on the left side and the selected item detail on the right side:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroll1" >
    <DockPanel>
        <ScrollViewer  Name="scroll2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" >
            <Really Long List Box />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Selected Item Details />           
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

(In the code above, scroll2 is always disable.)

In some cases "Selected Item Details" Height could be superior to the Window Height. In those cases the scroll1 should be enable. But in most cases it isn't. The only control bigger than the window height is the "Really Long List Box" so only scroll2 should be enable.

I know that the easiest way is to place scroll1 right above "Selected Item Details" like this:

```
<ScrollViewer  Name="scroll1"  >
    <Selected Item Details />      
</ScrollViewer>
```

But this is an in house framework that is divided in several UserControls and scroll1 control only serves as a phaceholder for child controls so I can't remove it.

Is there any way to enable only scroll2 when "Selected Item Details" fits on the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly set the height and width of a scrollviewer then it will take the height and width of the parent element. In this case, it looks like scroll2 is taking the height and width of the dock panel which is why scroll2 scrolling isn't enabled. Try setting the height and width of scroll2 and you should be able to scroll it.

Comment: Had to set it with a binding: <ScrollViewer  Name="scroll2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="{Binding ElementName=DockPanel, Path=ActualHeight}" > but it worked great.